# Where is this in Fallout 4?

Tags: fallout-4

I was listening to some music and saw this video of Fallout 4. From 1:40 to 1:45 it appears there is some sort of ship taking off and then crashing into a building.

Can someone tell me what quest this is, and/or where this might be located on the map?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's one possible outcome of the quest [Last Voyage of the U.S.S. Constitution](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Last_Voyage_of_the_U.S.S._Constitution).

It's just east of Bunker Hill.

Comment: Oh nice! Learn something new about this game every day. Thanks for this.